# How to use the Mehler kernel to get the solution of the Quantum harmonic oscillator with a given initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, fundamental-solution

In this wiki-article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel the fundamental solution of the differential equation for the Quantum harmonic oscillator is provided by the Mehler Kernel:

$K(x,y,t)=\frac{\exp(-\coth(2t)(x^2+y^2)/2-\operatorname{cosech}(2t)xy)}{\sqrt{2\pi\sinh(2t)}}$

Now if I have given some initial condition $\Psi(x,t=0)$ I should get the time evolution of $\Psi$ by convoluting $\Psi$ and $K$ (in an analogous matter as was done here for the heat equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions). But I am confused about the two spatial variables in $K$.

Can anybody tell me what Integral I actually have to solve to obtain $\Psi(x,t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is, explicitly, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Natural_length_and_energy_scales
in the first place.

The Mehler article you are in needs tweaking to imaginary time, so you solve the Schroedinger equation instead of the diffusion-type equation in that wiki. Besides,
the proper link to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_Examples:_Propagator_of_Free_Particle_and_Harmonic_Oscillator 
with the explanatory usage statement right before section 1.1 also gives you the same answer. Propagators propagate configurations at t=0 to such at arbitrary t, via the precise convolutions stated.

Comment: Note that answers which are mostly links to other sources are discouraged since these can change over time. Incorporating some of the source material into your answer will greatly improve its quality and accessibility.